# git flow for separate branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

Project now has develop and master branch.

everytime, when need release new versions, we use:

`git flow release publish v.x`

`git flow release finish v.x`

`git push origin master`

`git push origin develop`

`git push --tags`

now, something changed, the project needs to have a separate branch to publish special versions. This branch has codes that doesn't need to be merged into develop. We decided to keep this special version separately as a new branch rather than the develop branch.

So, how to use git flow to manage publishing this new branch?

Comment: If its never merged into develop, then how will it ever be released? Is it a hotfix for a particular release? There's a git flow workflow for hotfixing any particular branch which is *probably* what you want to read about.  https://github.com/nvie/gitflow#creating-featurereleasehotfixsupport-branches. You may benefit from a support branch instead. Depends on the details of your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a new project. Keeping another branch around is contrary to the the git-flow religion and should be corrected as soon as possible (if you intend to use the model, that is.)

On a more serious note, think about the two projects as they diverge further from each other. Soon the resemblance will barely seem recognizable, yet they share the same code history *and* the same code tree.

So if you think about it for a while and decide you want to really split this off, here's how you might go about it:

Create a new repo.

```
$ pwd
...projectOne
$ mkdir ../projectTwo
$ cd ../projectTwo
$ git init .
[ create new bare repo as an origin for this repo, add it ]
```

Use git-remote to add your old, split-brain repo as you did for origin (you did create a new origin for your new repo, didn't you?)

```
$ git remote add oldrepo ../projectOne
```

Use git-pull to pull the branch of your *new* project from the point where it diverged (or further back, if you think you want that history, also). You must pull a branch; I tried pulling a tag and that didn't work.

```
$ git pull oldrepo foo
```

You will now have a new repo with the code that corresponds to projectTwo and your original repo with projectOne, which you can trim and prune as you see fit.

You can now add git flow to your new repo:

```
$ git flow init
[ accept all defaults or rename as your organization sees fit ]
```

You can drop the remote connection, too:

```
$ git remote rm oldrepo
```

Make sure everyone is aware of the changes; maybe rename the branches on the old repo to *Deprecated do not use* or add some README files or whatever you need to do to convince your team not to use that repo for projectTwo any longer.